# Missing seperator. Stop error while installing makefile

Tags: makefile, centos7, vds

I am trying to install latest version of git on VDS server using the tutorial on [this website](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-centos-7) . According to the tutorial makefile must be installed. But when I run `sudo make install`  the error "`:1 *** missing seperator. Stop.`" is popping up.

My make file:

```
make configure
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running `sudo make install` from the correct directory?  Please edit your question to show the first few (10'ish) lines from the makefile.

Comment: I am running `sudo make install` in the directory where the make file is located. My make file has only those 2 line.

Comment: Those commands are meant to be run directly at the command prompt -- not as a makefile.